# Removing ServerSide Rendering in Next JS app (Next v 9.5.0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am working on removing the SSR from my Next app. Have removed SSR (i.e. use of getInitialProps) from all the other pages. But I'm stuck on _document.js file. Whenever I try to remove the section of getInitialProps from this file, it causes issue on UI because of ServerStyleSheets. So, how to resolve it? Basically, I want SSG and because of getInitialProps I am unable to do so.

```
import React from "react";
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import { ServerStyleSheets } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import loadingGif from "images/loading_gif.gif";
import {
  getLoaderOrGif,
  includesHostForDarkThemeCheck,
} from "../utils/themeSelector";
import { CircularProgress } from "@material-ui/core";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    const isLoaderOrGif = getLoaderOrGif(this.props.theme === "dark-theme");
    return (
      <html className={this.props.theme}>
        <Head>
          <Helmet
            htmlAttributes={{ lang: "en" }}
            title="Financial"
            meta={[
              {
                name: "viewport",
                content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1",
              },
              {
                property: "og:title",
                content: "",
              },
            ]}
          />
        </Head>

        <body>
          <div
            id="custom_loader"
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              fontSize: 32,
              background: isLoaderOrGif ? "#1e1e1e" : "white",
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              zIndex: 100,
            }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                position: "relative",
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                marginTop: "180px",
              }}
            >
            </div>
          </div>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
  const { req } = ctx;
  const isDarkTheme = req
    ? includesHostForDarkThemeCheck(req.headers.host)
    : false;
  const theme = isDarkTheme ? "dark-theme" : "light-theme";

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
    theme,
  };
};
```

I have tried removing the getInitialProps but am unable to proceed forward with it. And Since _document.js itself runs on server side, I am not sure whether removing getInitialProps from _document.js will work for SSG.